# Simple struct and vector combinations

Tags: c++

I want to print out multiple runners in a specific order. To make it easier this is what it should look like in the terminal:

```
Enter participants:

    Alexander Helm Abborberget LS
    Stina Stenby Freluga SSK
    Annette Larsson Fristad BSK
    Viktor Jonsson Gimo LS
    DONE

Surname First_name Club
==========================================
 Larsson Annette Fristad BSK
 Helm Alexander Abborberget LS
 Stenby Stina Freluga SSK
 Jonsson Viktor Gimo LS
```

As you can see you will have to input the runners first name `(eg. Anette), last name (eg. Larsson), and club (eg. Fristad BSK)`

And once the user types in `DONE`, you print out the runners details in the following order:

```
surname => first name => club
```

How can I do this? This is my attempt. It types out DONE instead which I don't want it to do and also I can't get it to type mulitple participants. I tried creating a subprogram making a vector of my struct (participants detail) with no success. As you can see I have commented that subprogram out.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Runner_Type
{
  string first_name;
  string surname;
  string club;
  string club_last;  
};

using Many_Runners_Type = vector<Runner_Type>;

void print(Runner_Type const & runners)

{
  cout << setw(3) << runners.surname << setw(15) << runners.first_name << setw(15) << runners.club << setw(3) << runners.club_last;

}

 // void print(Many_Runners_Type const & many_runners)
 // {
 //  for (Runner_Type const & runners : many_runners)
 //   {
 //    print(runners);
 //    cout << endl;
 //   }
 // }


int main()
  
{
  Runner_Type runners;
  Runner_Type many_runners;
     

  cout << "Enter participants: " << endl;

  while (true)
    {
      cin >> runners.first_name;

      if (runners.first_name == "DONE")

    {
      break;
    }

      cin >> runners.surname >> runners.club >> runners.club_last;          
    }

  print(runners);

  //print many_runners;


  return 0;
}
```

This is what my terminal looks like when I call my subprogram `print(runners)`:

```
Enter participants: 
Anette Larsson Fristad BSK
DONE
Larsson           DONE        FristadBSK
```

Don't worry about the spaces in between, I can easily fix that. That's just a small detail.

Comment: You have  a `many_runners` where you probably intended to store the runners. Do that, and print from it. Currently the `if (runners.first_name == "DONE")` triggers the print, and of course at that point the name *is* `"DONE"`.

Comment: Read the "first name" into a separate string first. Only update the runner's name if it's not "DONE".

Comment: Tip: dont give plural names, like "runners", to singular things. It is already confusing you, and will only get worse.